# Inherited external dependency origin in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Is there an easy way to see the origin of a external dependency that was inherited as a transitive one?

And is there a dependency graph or an "*Effective POM*" like other IDEs provide?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any option in Android Studio but running

```
gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies
    (where app is the name of application module)
```

Provides a useful dependency report in that form:

```
...
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
+--- com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2
+--- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.19.0
|    +--- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.19.0
|    |    +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.19.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
|    |    |    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1
|    |    |         +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.0.1
|    |    |         +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|    |    |         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3
|    |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
|    +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.19.0
```